# <noscript> for CSS only?

Tags: css

Is it possible to turn of CSS in some parts of page?
I can use `<noscript>`, but it turn javascript also...

Problem is that I have lots of global styling for lots of elements on page, and now I need to insert new ones ( lot's of new ones ), and I can't go one by one 1000 elements and change them...

Is it possible to do this without changing one by one?

Also, there is font-size: 70% scaling, and I can't overwrite that in my codes...

So how can I block this? Something like `<noscript>` but only for css ?

Comment: You could use JS to include your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<noscript>` does not turn off javascript, it gives code that is rendered only if javascript IS turned off.

I'm not entirely clear what you mean here. I *think* you mean that you want to apply very different styling to some new pieces in some of your pages. If they are in contiguous blocks you could put them in a div, and use that in your new styles. E.g. say you have:

css:

```
p {color: green; font-family: serif;}
a {color: blue;}
/* lots and lots of other declarations */
```

html:

```
<p>Here is a paragraph, there are a lot of these</p>
<p>Here is a paragraph I need in the new style, there are a lot of these too!</p>
```

Then you could do:

css:

```
p {color: green; font-family: serif;}
a {color: blue;}
/* lots and lots of other declarations */

.newStyle p {color: black; font-family: sans-serif;}
.newStyle a {color: red;}
/* lots and lots of other declarations */
```

html:

```
<p>Here is a paragraph, there are a lot of these</p>
<div class="newStyle">
  <p>Here is a paragraph I need in the new style, there are a lot of these too!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I used this: .destroyall * {
 vertical-align: auto;
 font-size: 100% !important;
 border: 0 none;
 outline: 0;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 text-align: auto;
 line-height: 1;
 vertical-align: auto;
 } But still font-size is inherited from 75%... How to eliminate this?

Comment: font-size is based on that of the containing box. Try .destroyall {font-size: 133.33333333%} (note: on .destroyall not on .destroyall *).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the find and replace tool found in many IDEs to replace the old bad css with your new better css or just remove it outright